# `column "..." specified more than once` error of view in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin, sql-view

I have a large query in a PostgreSQL database.
The Query is something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1, table2, ... WHERE table1.id = table2.id...
```

When I run this query as a sql query, the it returns the wanted row.

But when I tries to use the same query to create a view, it returns an error:

> error: column "id" specified more than once.

(I use pgAdminIII when executing the queries.)

I'll guess this happens because the resultset will have more than one column named "id". Is there someway to solve this, without writing all the column names in the query?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That happens because a view would have two id named columns, one from table1 and one from table2, because of the select *.

You need to specify which id you want in the view.

```
SELECT table1.id, column2, column3, ... FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.id = table2.id
```

The query works because it can have equally named columns...

```
postgres=# select 1 as a, 2 as a;
 a | a
---+---
 1 | 2
(1 row)

postgres=# create view foobar as select 1 as a, 2 as a;
ERROR:  column "a" duplicated
postgres=# create view foobar as select 1 as a, 2 as b;
CREATE VIEW
```

Comment: Is there a way to automatically prepend table names to column names in the result of a SELECT * query?

Comment: The problem with this solution is when you have too many columns to manually write on your select statement

Answer (score 17):

If only join columns are duplicated (i.e. have the same names), then you can get away with changing:

```
select *
from a, b
where a.id = b.id
```

to:

```
select *
from a join b using (id)
```

Comment: This didn't fix the error, but it is a nicer syntax anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it happened due to my mass in adding columns.
There were 5 columns in the previous version of create view statement.
I added 3 new ones in the final select but added only 2 to the list of columns at the create view statement beginning.
After fixing the column list the issue is gone.
As for me error msg is not helpful.

Answer (score -1):

If you got here because you are trying to use a function like `to_date` and getting the "defined more than once" error, note that you need to use a column alias for functions, e.g.:

```
to_date(o.publication_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS publication_date
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  column "?column?" specified more than once

When I tried to create the view which has 2 columns `'Hello'` and `'World'` with [SELECT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) as shown below:

```sql
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
  SELECT 'Hello', 'World';
```

So, I set `TEXT` type to 'Hello' as shown below, then I could create the view without error. *[The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html#id-1.9.3.97.7) says `the column name defaults to ?column?; also, the column data type defaults to text, ...`:

```sql
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
  SELECT TEXT 'Hello', 'World';
```

Or, I used [VALUES statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html) as shown below, then I could create the view without error:

```sql
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
  -- SELECT 'Hello', 'World';
  VALUES ('Hello', 'World');
```

In addition, If you try to create the view which has one column `('Hello', 'World')` with [SELECT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) as shown below:

```sql
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
  SELECT ('Hello', 'World');
```

Then, there is the error below:

> ERROR:  column "row" has pseudo-type record

Answer (score -3):

No built-in way in the language to solve it (and frankly, * is a bad practice in general because it can cause latent defects to arise as the table schemas change - you can do table1.*, table2.acolumn, tabl2.bcolumn if you want all of one table and selectively from another), but if PostgreSQL supports INFORMATION_SCHEMA, you can do something like:

```
DECLARE @sql AS varchar

SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ', ', '') 
    + '[' + TABLE_NAME + '].[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']'
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('table1', 'table2')
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION

PRINT @sql
```

And paste the results in to save a lot of typing.  You will need to manually alias the columns which have the same name, of course.  You can also code-gen unique names if you like (but I don't):

```
SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ', ', '') 
    + '[' + TABLE_NAME + '].[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] '
    + 'AS [' + TABLE_NAME + '_' + COLUMN_NAME + ']'
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('table1', 'table2')
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Comment: there is nothing like @SOMETHING in PostgreSQL.

Comment: There's also no using [] to quote identifiers.  And not CHAR() function. And no PRINT statement.