# SQL error error: column "pk1" specified more than once

Tags: sql

Any help? I can't find where the duplication is happening:

```
SELECT * 
FROM attempt 
INNER JOIN gradebook_grade GRADES 
    on(ATTEMPT.gradebook_grade_pk1=GRADES.pk1 )
INNER JOIN gradebook_main GRADES_TITLE 
    on (GRADES.gradebook_main_pk1 = GRADES_TITLE.pk1) 
INNER JOIN course_main Course 
    on (GRADES_TITLE.crsmain_pk1= Course.pk1)  
LEFT JOIN mainJoinedTable2 ENROLLMENT 
    ON (Enrollment.course_users_pk1 = GRADES.course_users_pk1)
```

Comment: Eliminate joins one at a time and see where the problem is focused. Also, what flavor of SQL are you using?

Comment: GRADES.pk1, GRADES_TITLE.pk1 and Course.pk1. You are selecting all of them with the `SELECT * ...` and they all have the same name. You can't do that. Assign an alias in your select clause by naming each column you are selecting explicitely.

Comment: Are you trying to create a view with this `SELECT` statement?

Comment: This is one of the reason you should *always* be explicit about what to select, and *never* use `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 1):

You have pk1 column multiple tables so you have to specify which tables pk1 you are going to project in select statement , so you can Try like below

```
 SELECT attempt .* ,GRADES.*,Course.*
    FROM attempt 
    INNER JOIN gradebook_grade GRADES 
        on(ATTEMPT.gradebook_grade_pk1=GRADES.pk1 )
    INNER JOIN gradebook_main GRADES_TITLE 
        on (GRADES.gradebook_main_pk1 = GRADES_TITLE.pk1) 
    INNER JOIN course_main Course 
        on (GRADES_TITLE.crsmain_pk1= Course.pk1)  
    LEFT JOIN mainJoinedTable2 ENROLLMENT 
        ON (Enrollment.course_users_pk1 = GRADES.course_users_pk1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick search brought me there : [View error in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207964/view-error-in-postgresql)

Basically, you join many tables that have identical column names (in your instance, at least the following : `gradebook_grade.pk1`,`course_main.pk1`,`gradebook_main.pk1`). The fact that you `SELECT *` makes it so the output will have many pk1 columns and that will be ambiguous. You need to specify each column in your `SELECT` and rename them with aliases.