# Using a union or union all in Materialized View causing an Error in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, union-all, materialized-views, postgresql-10

I am creating a materialized view which contains a union query and am getting the  following error: column "column1" specified more than once.

What are the potential causes of this error?

How do i fix this this?

Here is an example of what my code looks like:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.view_name_mv
(
     "column1",
     "column2",
     "column3"
)
as 
select 
     tn1.column1, 
     tn1.column2,
     tn1.column3
from schema.table_name1 tn1,
     schema.table_name2 tn2
where tn1.column1 = tn2.column1
and   tn1.column2  = tn2.column2
union all 
select 
     tn1.column1, 
     tn1.column2, 
     tn1.column3
from schema.table_name1 tn1, 
     schema.table_name3 tn3
where tn1.column1 = tn3.column1
and   tn1.column2 = tn3.colum2;
```

NOTE: running the query standalone in PGAdmin 4 will run fine but using the same query to create a materialized view will throw the error listed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when you're joining tables and you don't specify which column belongs to each table when both columns have the same name. I suppose those values column1, column2 and column3 are fake, and as they are full of sintax erros as shown below, I can't really know if in your real code you forgot to rename a column.

Try to look for something like this in you real code:

```
select column1 from 
schema.table1 tn1, schema.table2 tn2 
where tn1.column1 = tn2.column2
```

In this example the *column1* isn't specified if it is from table1 or table2

Sintax erros on this example:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.view_name_mv
(
     "column1",
     "column2",
     "column3", << remove this comma
)


union all 
select 
     tn1.colum1, << the name here is wrong, replace to column1
     tn1.colum2, << the name here is wrong, replace to column2
     tn1.column3
```

Comment: Yes, these are typos while writing the question. I fixed the typos in the question. I don't have a missing alias in the actual code. Do you know if Postgres is interpreting the SQL in a way that would cause this issue?

Comment: Error: column "column1" specified more than once.
SQL state: 42701

The above is the entire error...nothing more

Comment: @RexCoolCodeCharles I created your view on SQLFiddle with Postgres 9.6 and your materialized view works there.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/31a7fe/1

Comment: I think your error is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207964/view-error-in-postgresql

See if it helps. In this error he got the same error of yours because one of his columns wasn't specified in the select.

Comment: @RexCoolCodeCharles any news?